# Error: SliverGeometry is not valid: The "scrollExtent" is negative. in flutter Sliver Grid View Laout

Tags: flutter, sliver-grid

EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
SliverGeometry is not valid: The "scrollExtent" is negative.
The RenderSliver that returned the offending geometry was: RenderSliverGrid#f9778 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT:
  creator: SliverGrid ← MediaQuery ← SliverPadding ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#15db4] ←
    Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ←
    RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#30301] ← _PointerListener ← Listener
    ← ⋯
  parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: SliverConstraints(AxisDirection.down, GrowthDirection.forward, ScrollDirection.idle,
```

Comment: I Answer this issue at this link [Answed by Satyam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972563/scrollextent-is-negative-in-flutter/66761316#66761316)

Answer (score 19):

I found I was getting the 'scrollExtent is negative' error when I passed 0 items to the GridView.builder. This was occurring prior to my data being loaded.

In my build function, I check to see if the List of items is zero, and if so, I render an empty Container() instead of the Gridview. This stopped the error from happening.

I believe this is a bug with the GridView, as it should be able to gracefully handle no records.

Comment: That helped man. thanks!.

Comment: this help for some reason. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a related issue here. Still unresolved.

[ScrollExtent is negative in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63972563/scrollextent-is-negative-in-flutter)

Btw, you can check on Github.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39963

And for the reproduce of the error:
https://dartpad.dev/2630a061cf2632a1ffd6fb6c13c94e4c

Answer (score 1):

for me, that is the old code causing exception: [old code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJiJP.png)

then I began searching and tried some changes.
At the point I found
**gridDelegate** was causing Exception.

then after some changes: [new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgsPY.png)

I got my Exception fixed.

**Note: Don't use any Mathematical operation that may produce a
double value!**

I hope that is helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your code looks like, but I was using NotificationListener on my GridView.builder.

I got this error when I cleared the contents of my Gridview. (In my code, I have a search filter, which clears the search results on save, then calls the search function). Once I added a simple flag to show a progress indicating while loading and a message if the results are 0, the error went away.